# How to substitute a variable in a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a function that pulls out special modifiers from a string passed to a function

```
function parseContext(record, txtInput) {
    var context = String((txtInput.match(/(^\@[\w\n]*)/g) || [""])[0]).replace("@", "");
    record.entry = txtInput;
    if (command && command.length) {
        txtInput = String(txtInput).replace("/" + command, "");
        record.command = command;
        record.entry = txtInput;
    }
    return record;
}
```

What I'm not sure how to do (in this case), is how to abstract it so I can parse out an arbitrary leading character in the form of something like:

```
function parseModifier(record, modifier, txtInput) {
    var command = String((txtInput.match(/(^\  ---what goes here? --- [\w\n]*)/g) || [""])[0]).replace(modifier, "");
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var re = new RegExp('(^\\' + anyVariable + '[\w\n]*)', 'g');
var command = String((txtInput.match(re || [""])[0]).replace(modifier, "");
```

Using the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor allows you to use any variable, since it takes a string as input.

Comment: Thanks!  added a closing paren to the second line (edit pending I believe)

Comment: my edit was incorrect, should be: new RegExp('(^\\' + modChar + '[\\w\\n]*)', 'g'),